# Does using "array style" tables give faster read access than using "map style" tables?

Tags: lua

I'm writing a game in Lua using Love2D.

Each entity obviously has an x,y position, which is just a table called "position" which holds {x, y} (i.e., {10, 4}).

Up until now I've been implementing the table using the array operator, so to get the x value, I'd invoke position[1], and to get y value I'd invoke position[2].

For readability, however, I'd much rather invoke position.x, and position.y.  This would involve using the tables in their "map" style, like `position = {x=10, y=4}`.

While the array lookup time must obviously be O(1), I'm afraid using the map style would give worse results, due to the fact that maps tend to be a million times more complicated internally than a simple array.

In a way, I doubt the performance difference would matter much, even if it's called a million times a minute in my main game loop.  I just want to have a better understanding of the tools I'm using to create this game.

Thanks!

Comment: Arrays are quicker to loop over the oh (Numeric/ipairs)

Comment: "Map style" does not affect performance. Using consecutive, positive integer keys, starting at 1, does. `{10, 4}` would (probably) result in the same internal structure as `{[2]=4,[1]=10}`. It's really up to Love2D and that's where the concept of "array" resides; not in the Lua language or libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excerpt from [Implementation of Lua 5.0](http://www.lua.org/doc/jucs05.pdf) by Roberto et al.:

> Until Lua 4.0, tables were implemented strictly as hash tables: all pairs were
>   explicitly stored. Lua 5.0 brought a new algorithm to optimize the use of tables
>   as arrays: it optimizes pairs with integer keys by not storing the keys and storing the values in an actual array. More precisely, in Lua 5.0, tables are implemented as hybrid data structures: they contain a hash part and an array part.
>
> [...]
>
> This hybrid scheme has two advantages. First, access to values with integer keys is faster because no hashing is needed. Second, and more important, the array part takes roughly half the memory it would take if it were stored in the hash part, because the keys are implicit in the array part but explicit in the hash part. As a consequence, if a table is being used as an array, it performs as an array, as long as its integer keys are dense. Moreover, no memory or time penalty is paid for the hash part, because it does not even exist.

So, yes, if you use Lua 5 or greater, then there should be significant difference in speed and memory in only using the table as an array.

> I doubt the performance difference would matter much, even if it's called a million times a minute in my main game loop.

It's better that you benchmark before concluding on anything related to performance, since it's usually counter-intuitive. You may be OK with the performance that you can take the hit for readability - but do so in an informed manner.

Perhaps you don't have to sacrifice readability if you can write helper functions to get the same data:

```
function X(t)
    return t[1]
end

function Y(t)
    return t[2]
end

local pos = { 8, 1 }
print(X(pos))
```

Comment: Your helper function looks gross, what you should do is use the __index metamethod to "reroute" x/y to 1/2

Comment: My __index would've looked like ```function(t,k) return k == 'x'and t[1] or k == 'y' and t[2] end```

Comment: Also metatables are handled c-side, so my theory is it could be faster (or at least about the same) then a helper function/hash part of the table. Besides, chances are he'll want some of the metamethods like __add to add coordinates together later anyway.

Comment: How's that helper is better than just having plain `.x` key? It is inherently much slower than plain table access.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov We're talking about the metamethod or a simple getter function solution? Why would `function X(t) return t[1] end` be slower than the hash table lookup?

Comment: @legends2k, because function call is pretty much THE slowest operation you can imagine in most languages. It involves creating new stack frame, moving arguments and returns around, saving current state and then restoring it. In case of Lua you aslo STILL HAVE your table lookup, because Lua first tries to perform regular lookup and only then goes to your function when nothing is found by regular means. So you spend time on both orginal lookup, one more lookup for `__index` key in metatable and then also on your function.

Comment: @legen then ```or nil``` at the end?

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov I agree, this was the reason I originally had only a single lookup function (no metamethods); I've reverted to that revision now. I understand that even calling `X(p)` may be slower due to the [function prologue and epilogue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue) than Lua's implementation of hash key lookup. Thanks for chiming in!

Comment: @warspyking Yes, that should do, however metamethods should be costlier like Oleg also notes. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: I still stand by my C argument.

Comment: And what's the point in reverting when your version isn't as readable as .x, and is slower than .x?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, array will always be faster than tables, however difference is usualy neglible compared to time spent on performing other tasks. Unless you will constantly access your new `.x` and `.y` keys in very tight loops with thousands of iterrations you shouldn't even bother.

However, if you do there's several apporoaches to mitigate any difference.

Localize your retrieved values:

```
-- Old - 3 lookups
result = obj.x + --[[ some long calculations ]] obj.x + --[[ more long calculations ]] obj.x

-- New - 1 lookup
local x = obj.x
result = x + --[[ some long calculations ]] x + --[[ more long calculations ]] x
```

Continue to use arrays, but define "constants" for index's magic numbers to improve readability

```
local X = 1
local Y = 2
print("Object coordinates are X: " .. obj[X] .. ", Y: " .. obj[Y])
```

Comment: I like the last solution here; it's simple, effective and hidden in plain sight that I missed it. *sigh*